# Magento upgrade, Database file

Tags: upgrade

I am currently updating from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 my question is, the database file I am using was from a few days ago, can I just create a new copy of my DB and put it in place. I am not sure if the update created any new tables or fields in the database, what will happen when I use my copy that was not present during the update, do I have to run an upgrade:schema or will the backend just create the missing fields when I go to populate them in the MAG Admin? I am just not sure how or when the new fields get created.

Thank you for any help you can offer, have a great day to everyone that makes Stack Exchange great!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the following cli commands after updating the codebase to 2.4.3.

- setup:upgrade
- setup:di:compile
- setup:static-content:deploy

After you've updated the codebase you won't be able to successfully load any frontend/admin pages until running those commands, magento will throw an error as the database structure and data will be out of date. That first command will update the database as needed.

When in doubt consult the documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Podsix, I understand that setup:upgrade must be run, I have successfully upgraded the site and its modules on my staging server. My question is, I have a 2.4.2 version database file on my current site which is up to date, however its on my 2.4.2 live site, will it be a problem when I export it and use it with my 2.4.3? If there are fields that have been added to the database during the upgrade, will they get added again, Sorry for being confusing. Do I have to do anything to my 2.4.2 database file when I move it to my staging server with and up to dat copy Mag 2.4.3 ?

Comment: So after rereading your answer, running setup:upgrade should add the fields if any to the DB file if they are missing. Thanks.